# How do I turn off deprecated warnings of the cakephp console?

Tags: console, cakephp-1.3, deprecated

I'm using CakePHP 1.3.16 with PHP 5.4.6. The new PHP version caused a few deprecated warnings with old 1.3 CakePHP applications, which were fixed by updating to the 1.3.16 version. Unfortunately, I'm still getting deprecated warnings when using **the console**, which is quite annoying, and I can't find the place to turn them off. Here's what I tried:

- I checked the error reporting in the php.ini files, in both /etc/php5/cli/php.ini (which should be used by command line php scripts) and /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini: in both cases it says `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`.
- I modified all lines saying `error_reporting($reporting)` in the /cake/libs/configure.php to say `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT)`.
- I ran a recursive search for 'error_reporting' in the cake directory. Whenever it showed up, deprecated warnings were switched off by default. Still, I am getting them on the console.

Did anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 10):

For **cakephp 3.*** just set the following value in your config/app.php file:

```
// in config/app.php
'Error' => [
      'errorLevel' => E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_USER_DEPRECATED,

]
```

Comment: It was better if your answers explanation was given too! Thanks

Comment: This worked for me. Explanation from ChatGPT:
The E_ALL constant represents all error levels, including warnings and notices, while the E_DEPRECATED and E_USER_DEPRECATED constants represent errors that occur when using deprecated code. The bitwise operator ^ is used to perform a bitwise XOR operation, which effectively removes the E_DEPRECATED and E_USER_DEPRECATED flags from the E_ALL constant.

In other words, this configuration is specifying that all errors should be logged except for deprecated code warnings and notices.

Answer (score 3):

In **app/Config/core.php** change `debug` mode to 0:

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

Comment: Then you should accept the answer. Two years are enough to make that decision.